# Handle dots in Soap names with PHP

Tags: php, soap, soapui

I have a wsdl that when opened in soapui shows methods named this way:

- DTL.GP.03.RC.Method1
- DTL.GP.04.RC.Method2
- etc

I can't find a way to use those names with PHP Soapclient. The dots in the names screw up the code. Anyone knows a way?

Answer (score 1):

See http://php.net/manual/es/function.call-user-func.php. And __getFunctions returns list of available SOAP functions.

**Here some examples:**

```
$client = new SoapClient(__DIR__."/helloservice.wsdl");
echo var_export($client->__getFunctions(), true);

$param1 = "nacho";

echo "eg 1\n";
echo call_user_func(array($client, "DTL.GP.03.RC.Method1"), $param1 /* , ... */)."\n";

echo "eg 2\n";
$method="DTL.GP.03.RC.Method1";
echo $client->$method($param1)."\n";
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
array (
  0 => 'string DTL.GP.03.RC.Method1(string $firstName)',
)eg 1
Hello nacho
eg 2
Hello nacho
```

I tried this in PHP 5.5.27, but also works in PHP 5.3.